Shutdown QuickFIX/J application externally
A QuickFIX java application could be started by using the
Acceptor.start() or Initiator.start() methods.
Is there a way to send a shutdown signal to the application that is running, instead of killing it?

Stop()? Could work.. ;)

I want to shut it down externally. Not from the same program

OK, I've added that important word "externally" to the question. Maybe I was confused because you mentioned start(). However, I don't know what you want to achieve exactly. If it is sufficient to disconnect the sessions then maybe access via JMX could be what you are looking for. If you really want to shutdown the whole app then that has to be implemented in your own application's code. https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/jmx.html

Yes, disconnecting should be fine. OK, I will try JMX then. Thanks for the link

From what I read in your question, it has nothing to do with QuickFIX/J itself. You are asking how to send signals to your application.

If it is sufficient to disconnect the sessions then maybe access via JMX could be what you are looking for.
See here for example code: https://quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/jmx.html
If you really want to shutdown the whole app then that has to be implemented in your own application's code.
